# MS Access 2010 - Prompting user to save changes

Tags: ms-access, vba, beforeupdate

I have developed a form and I would like to prompt the user to save changes before they navigate away from the modified record.

If the user attempts to navigate away, I want a prompt to appear asking if they wish to save changes, upon which they may select "Yes" or "No".

I have been informed that the `Before Update` event is the one I need to focus on, but I keep receiving the "the expression before update you entered as the event property setting produced the following error" message.

These are the steps I take before reaching the error:

1. Change view to Form View
2. Make a change anywhere in the record via the form
3. Attempt to navigate away from form via navi-buttons that I put into my form (which work just fine if no changes are made but which fail to do anything if a single change has been made)
4. Nothing happens, so I revert to Design View, to receive the following error notification

[image: Error notification]

5. I press OK and then receive this message:

[image: Error message 2]

And then I go back to Square One.

Furthermore, any Conditional Formatting has stopped working altogether since this problem has arisen; I do not know for certain if the two are linked, but thought it worth mentioning.

Any ideas how this can be achieved (ideally error-free)?  Unfortunately, I cannot post my system up as it deals with highly confidential data.

**UPDATE:**

I have tried a variety of codes which I have modified, all to no avail.  At present, I have removed any such code altogether, but the code I have tried in the past is something to the effect of:

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)

Dim ctl As Control

On Error GoTo Err_BeforeUpdate

If Me.Dirty Then
   If MsgBox("Do you want to save?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, _
           "Save Record") = vbNo Then
      Me.undo
   End If
End If

Exit_BeforeUpdate:
   Exit Sub

Err_BeforeUpdate:
   MsgBox Err.Number & " " & Err.Description
   Resume Exit_BeforeUpdate
End Sub
```

Comment: Please post the code.  It sounds like you've got it completely wrong.

Comment: Question updated - any ideas?

Comment: Put a code break in the code at the On Error GoTo... line, and then when the code breaks and shows that line highlighted, press F8 repeatedly (SLOWLY!) until you get the message.  That will tell you exactly which line of code it doesn't like.  Post that line of code and the exact error you get and we'll see if something jumps out.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion; I have set the code break on line "On Error...", but unfortunately, when I debug, it asks me to run a macro (which I do not have), and as such when I press F8, nothing happens.

Comment: Have you compacted & repaired and decompiled recently? I hope you do not intend to use a subform with this idea. The default for MS Access is to save, and it takes quite a lot more work to stop a save, usually you need an unbound form.

Comment: Yes, I have C&R'd multiple times but unfortunately to no avail.  The  main problem is that there was no problem (everything actually worked fine for a time) up until a particular nano-second where *something* changed, but what exactly that *something* is, I have no idea as I had not made any further changes to any code.

Comment: Did you try the decompile as suggested? Also, do you have 'Option Explicit' and have you compiled all code? Assuming 'yes' to all, have you tried creating an empty database and importing all objects?

Comment: Look at the properties of the form.  It looks like you have set the Form to run "Before Update" (notice the space between the words in your error message?) when it should be running "BeforeUpdate" (no space between words).

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn I created a new project and imported everything - HURRAH!  Everything (conditional formatting included) now works!  Post this up as an answer so that I may select it as my accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

The default behaviour for a Microsoft Access bound form is to automatically save the record whenever the user does the following:

Moves to another record, Closes The form or explicitly clicks the save button on the ribbon

Therefore I thinks it may be redundant asking the user to confirm if they wish to save.

The forms before update event is generally used for validation so you can check the data that has been entered into the controls and decide in code whether to allow the data to be saved.

To prevent the data from being saved you would change the Cancel variable for example:

```
Cancel=True
MsgBox "There is a problem with the data entry", vbExclamation, "Please Check Your Data"
```

The user would then have to press escape or click Undo on the ribbon to escape out of edit mode

Regarding the error you are getting please look into and try the decompile switch documented at the following web page:

[Decompile Switch](https://fmsinc.com/MicrosoftAccess/Errors/Bad_DLL_Calling_Convention.asp)

I occasionally get errors when working with and saving VBA code over and over.  Doing the decompile can usually fix this problem.  However make sure you do a backup of the database before you start.

Also you could try exporting out your form as a text file and then importing it back in again using the following code which will help if the form has become corrupted:

```
    Application.SaveAsText acForm, stringFormName, stringFolderName & "\" & stringFormName & ".txt"
    Application.LoadFromText acForm, stringFormName, stringFileName
```

Comment: I imported the project into a new database and all is now working.  Thank you for your efforts!

Answer (score 0):

1. Open your form in Design View
2. Right-click on the form and click on "Properties" from the pop-up menu
3. Scroll down to the "Before Update" event
4. All the way on the right you should see a box with an ellipse ("...") in it.  Click that box to open the code associated with the Before Update event.
5. If it opens to a blank sub, you haven't assigned the event properly.  Make sure the event is called "BeforeUpdate" (one word) and not "Before Update" (two words).

Your error indicates that this is likely the cause of the issue.

Comment: I took a look but "Before Update" does not appear anywhere; however, I imported the project into a new database and all is now working!  Thank you so much for your help, however.